# <identifier> expected (Java)

Tags: java, identifier

I'm new to Java. I'm writing code that will create an object of Pascal's Triangle and a method that will allow me to get Newton's binomial factor value. I am getting the enigmatic " expected" error that does not tell me much. I've searched through Google and SO, but to no avail. I'm sorry for the comments and class names which are in my native language, but that's what the tutor wanted. I have the code working in C++ if that is of any help.

The problem is at lines 17 and 56 (the method and the constructor).

Here's the code of the class:

```
package kp_lista04_java;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class TrojkatPascalaException extends Exception {
    TrojkatPascalaException(String w) {super(w);}
}

class TrojkatPascala {
    private List<List<Integer>> matrix;
    private List<Integer> row_final;
    private List<Integer> row_temporary;

    public int wspolczynnik (int param_r, int param_p) throws (TrojkatPascalaException) {
        // r - numerator wiersza Pascala
        int r = param_r;
        // p - numerator elementu wiersza Pascala
        int p = param_p;
        if (p < 0 || p > r) {
            throw new TrojkatPascalaException("    Element " + p + ": index out of range");
        }
        else {
            // q - wartosc zadanego elementu
            // wiemy, ze zerowe i ostatnie elementy sa zawsze rowne 1
            int q;
            if (p == 0 || p == r) {
                q = 1;
            }
            // wiemy, ze pierwsze i przedostatnie elementy
            // sa rowne numerowi wiersza
            else if (p == 1 || p == r-1) {
                q = r;
            }
            // przejscie (funkcja w rozumieniu matematycznym)
            // miedzy wierszem trojkata Pascala
            // a zapisanym w pamieci wektorem

            // w - numerator elementu wektora
            else {
                int w;
                if (p < Math.ceil((float) r/2)) {
                    w = p - 2;
                }
                else {
                    w = r - p - 2;
                }
                q = matrix.get(r).get(w);
            }
            return q;
        }
    }

    TrojkatPascala (int n_param) throws (TrojkatPascalaException) {
        int n = n_param;
        if (n < 0) {
            throw new TrojkatPascalaException("Row " + n + ": index out of domain");
        }
        else {
            matrix = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
            for (int u = 0; u < n + 1; ++u) {
                row_final = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                row_temporary = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                row_final.clear();
                // inicjalizacja - wartosc elementu 2 w wierszu 4
                // elementow zerowych, pierwszych, ostatnich i przedostatnich
                // nie zapamietujemy
                row_final.add( 6 );

                //
                //// petla generujaca odpowiedni wiersz
                //

                // i - numer budowanego wiersza
                for (int i = 5; i < u+1; ++i) {
                    // wektor roboczy
                    row_temporary.clear();

                    // tworzony jest pierwszy element wektora roboczego
                    row_temporary.add(i-1 + row_final.get(0));

                    // j - liczba elementow wektora roboczego
                    // korzystamy z faktu, ze wystarczy zapamietac
                    // ~polowe elementow (wiersze sa symetryczne)
                    int j = Math.ceil((float) i/2) - 2;

                    // r - numer tworzonego elementu wiersza roboczego
                    for (int r = 1; r < j; ++r) {
                        // korzystamy z zaleznosci rekurencyjnej tworzenia
                        // elementow
                        row_temporary.add(row_final.get(r-1) + row_final.get(r));
                    }

                    // w przypadku parzystych wierszy dodajemy dwukrotnosc
                    // ostatniego elementu poprzedniego wiersza
                    // wynika to z faktu, ze wiersze sa symetryczne
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        row_temporary.add(2 * row_final.get(row_final.size() - 1));
                    }

                    // zastepujemy wiersz wejsciowy
                    // wierszem wyjsciowym (roboczym)
                    row_final.clear();
                    row_final = row_temporary;
                    // usuwamy zbedna kopie wiersza roboczego z pamieci
                    row_temporary.clear();
                }
                matrix.add(row_final);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the code of the test class:

```
package kp_lista04_java;

public class TrojkatPascalaTest {
    public static void main( String[] arg ) {
        try {

            if (arg.length == 0) {
                throw new TrojkatPascalaException("No arguments were given");
            }

            else {
                TrojkatPascala pascal_triangle;
                // n - zadany numer wiersza      
                int n = Integer.parseInt(arg[0]);
                System.out.println("Row range from " + 0 + " to " + n);
                pascal_triangle = new TrojkatPascala(n);
                // p - zadany numer elementu w zadanym wierszu
                for (int i = 1; i < arg.length; i = i + 2) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("-----");
                        try {
                            Integer.parseInt(arg[i]);
                        }
                        catch (NumberFormatException e){
                            throw new TrojkatPascalaException("Row " + arg[i] + ": index is not an integer");
                        }
                        int r = Integer.parseInt(arg[i]);
                        if (r < 0 || r > n) {
                            throw new TrojkatPascalaException("Row " + r + ": index out of range");
                        }
                        System.out.println("Row " + r + ":");
                        System.out.println("    Element range from 0 to " + r);
                        try {
                            Integer.parseInt(arg[i+1]);
                        }
                        catch (NumberFormatException e){
                            throw new TrojkatPascalaException("    Element " + arg[i+1] + ": index is not an integer");
                        }
                        int p = Integer.parseInt(arg[i+1]);
                        int elemele = pascal_triangle.wspolczynnik(r, p);
                        System.out.println("    Element " + p + ": " + elemele);
                    }
                    catch (TrojkatPascalaException w) {
                        System.out.println(w.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (TrojkatPascalaException w) {
            System.out.println(w.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paste the exact and complete error message, and tell us which line it refers to in the posted code.

Comment: Where is line 17 and 56 in your posted code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no parentheses around the `Exception` in the method and constructor.

So change:

```
public int wspolczynnik (int param_r, int param_p) throws (TrojkatPascalaException) {
```

to:

```
public int wspolczynnik (int param_r, int param_p) throws TrojkatPascalaException {
```

And same for the constructor.

Comment: Thank you. This is what happens when a tired (and a beginner) person translates C++ to Java.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
public int wspolczynnik (int param_r, int param_p) throws (TrojkatPascalaException)
```

and

```
TrojkatPascala (int n_param) throws (TrojkatPascalaException)
```

respectively to

```
public int wspolczynnik (int param_r, int param_p) throws TrojkatPascalaException
TrojkatPascala (int n_param) throws TrojkatPascalaException
```